# node js crawler and expresse

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I want to know how to send result after crawling  using npm crawler .
I got this error

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Any help ?

```js
app.get('/', async (req, result) => {
    var c = new Crawler({
        maxConnections: 10,
        callback: function(error, res, done) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else

            {
                var $ = res.$;
                $('.ajax_block_product').each(function(i, elem) {
                    var x = $(elem)
                    produit.site = x.find('a').attr('href').split('w.').pop().split('.tn')[0];
                    produit.image = x.find('img').attr('src');
                    produit.lien = x.find('a').attr('href');
                    produit.Nom_produit = x.find('a').attr('title');
                    produit.Prix = x.find('span.price').text();
                    produit.Etat = x.find('span.available-now').text();
                    produits.push(produit);

                });
                $('.item-product').each(function(i, elem) {
                    var x = $(elem)
                    produit.site = x.find('a').attr('href').split('w.').pop().split('.tn')[0];
                    produit.image = x.find('img').attr('src');
                    produit.lien = x.find('a').attr('href');
                    produit.Nom_produit = $(x.find('a')).find('p').text().substr(0, 27);
                    produit.Prix = x.find('span.price').text();
                    produit.Etat = x.find('span.available-now').text();
                    produits.push(produit);


                });
                console.log(produits)
                result.send(produits)
            }
            done();

        },
    })

    c.queue([url1, url2, url3, url4])

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the headers under `res.headers({})` as an object, you can find more here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler#callbacks.

Also, I would recommend to set you code in the `else` scope, so it will only run the code when there is no error.

To eliminate another source of errors, you might want to discard the REST API you do in line 1 with `app.get`, i would just run the command normally by calling it locally to test it.

Comment: ok thnx but how do i supposed to send the result to a web client (angular)

Comment: i just recommended to do so before you work with the frontend, the idea is to make a POC (proof of concept) locally without too many other code surrounding it, especially with something like crawling, which more often then not can get tiresome.
Later on, I would pack the crawler in a different file and then call the function in `app.get()`, to prevent the code from beeing messy.